# Pin foundations

Tags: concrete, foundation, footings

Are patented pin foundations worth their price?

Would simply drilling holes into a concrete block, driving rods into the ground to frost line depth, and securing the rods to concrete block with anchoring epoxy to adequately replicate a pin foundation?

Perhaps my search engine querying isn't sophisticated enough, is what's described above, concrete blocks with rods or metal bars, available at specialty distributors/retailers either online or in-store?

Comment: Or dig a diamond shaped hole, pound the pins, then fill the hole (plus maybe a tube above) with concrete. Same idea, right?

Comment: yep, perhaps it would be easier to mix and fill the concrete in a hole instead of drilling holes? the concrete hole seems more permanent. the pin foundation has a [convenient option to remove](https://youtu.be/0dXqDaVj3mQ?t=3m30s). likely the rods and block needs to be a specific material, perhaps a metal and dense concrete, to be able to remove.

Comment: Ah, yes. Perhaps a coating or wrap on the pipes for the cast version to prevent sticking to the concrete. But, all moot to your original question. I couldn't find any "diamond pier alternatives" in my searches either.